# how to write function for multiple if-else statements

Tags: java, function, if-statement

I am new to Java. I have lots of multiple if-else statements. For code optimization purpose I need to write one function for all if else logic.

```
if (obj.getJSONObject("page_1").has("city")) {
    sn.city = (String) obj.getJSONObject("page_1").get("city").toString();
} else {
    sn.city = null;
}

// param 2 - locality

if (obj.getJSONObject("page_1").has("locality")) {
    locality = (String) obj.getJSONObject("page_1").get("locality").toString();
} else {
    locality = null;
}
```

I have like 110 if -else statements. I don't have any idea how to optimize the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might write a function something like:

```
static String getToStringOrNull(JSONObject parent, String key) {
  return parent.has(key) ? parent.get(key).toString() : null;
}
```

which you can then call like

```
sn.city = getToStringOrNull(obj.getJSONObject("page_1"), "city");
locality = getToStringOrNull(obj.getJSONObject("page_1"), "locality");
```

Comment: @EvangelineLydia You're welcome. You can show your appreciation by accepting this (or another answer, if another one works better for you) using the tick on the left.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best use would be this notation ([ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java)):

```
sn.city = (obj.getJSONObject("page_1").has("city")) ? 
                    (String) obj.getJSONObject("page_1").get("city").toString() : null;
```

The part before `?` stands for the if-statement, the second part if the condition was fulfilled and the last part otherwise.

Comment: You need to be careful with this - there are a number of repeated keys that you need to make sure you change in all places (`"page1"` and `"city"`) - it is very easy to make copy/paste errors. It might be better if you don't need to specify them multiple times.

Comment: Yes, I agree that your solution is better in terms of both readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

For all direct fields of your class, you may use reflection (and you could do the same work on the sn object if you want ) :

```
Class aClass = this.getClass();

Field[] fields = aClass.getFields();

for (Field field : fields) {


   String value = (obj.getJSONObject("page_1").has(field.getName())) ?
            (String) obj.getJSONObject("page_1").get(field.getName()).toString() : null;

   field.set(this, value);
}
```